# How to mark a new api added in new version in c#, like @Since or @Version in java

Tags: c#, .net, api, version

How c# mark a new api added in a newer version of project.
Example MinBy() method in linq added in .net6.0.
How to know what api added,when it added.
How do i mark for new api added to another user/ developer know that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no attributes like that in .NET/C# best you can do is reading the release announcement.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6/

Comment: Well, for .NET framework code, the documentation is way better than release notes.  For example, the "Applies To" section of the `MinBy` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.minby?view=net-6.0

Comment: So they do not mark it in their code, how do they manually remember and note it?.
I don't see any signs represent that